# Setting picklist values dynamically for standard object

Tags: salesforce

I want to add a custom picklist field to a `Case` object in Salesforce, so that the field value can be used at the time of a new case creation. But I don't want to add the picklist values at the time of field creation, the values of picklist should be dynamically generated depending on another object's field value. Is there any way?

Comment: do you have any code that you could provide for us to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is linked somewhere in the case (via lookup for example) then looks like [Workflow + Field Update](https://cs7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_rules.htm) would be good candidates.

If it's to be a fully system-generated field that users can never edit then you should use a formula field (it's value will be automatically calculated whenever case is viewed or retrieved with SOQL so "always fresh". Workflow-based value will generally not update on Case if something changes on your other object). Start the creator of new field on Case and click the help icon to read more about formula fields.